How do I disable in viewport when there's no button to do so?
Correct me if I'm wrong, but I heard that disabling in viewport tells blender to stop processing the disabled objects, improving performance. I don't see the button to do so.
Example from another question:

Mine:


Open the Filters popover, from there you can enable the display of that restriction toggle:

